# problem in requesting a url through ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am making a ajax request to some url. but each time i am getting an error as status.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/",
    type: 'GET',
    complete: function(jqXHR,textStatus) {

                        alert(textStatus);

         }
    })
```

each time i get "error" in textStatus. what m i doing wrong.

```
EDIT:
```

ckeck it http://jsfiddle.net/bhXbh/54/

Comment: that is because you are requesting a page in a different domain

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to make a cross domain ajax call, which is forbidden by the browser's [Same Origin Policy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Assuming your remote url allows for [JSONP requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), and assuming you're using JQuery > 1.5, you can simply add `crossDomain:true` to your `$.ajax()` params.

Comment: Yea you're trying to fetch `http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/` which is not JSON. JSONP works by wrapping the JSON response in a callback function. When you fetch the url, you acknowledge the callback param so the browser thinks you're just including an external function. Yahoo discovered the technique a few years back.

Comment: will this url work url: solrURL+"/solr/db/select/?qt=dismax&wt=json&&start="+start+"&rows="+end+"&q="+query+"&json.wrf=?"

Comment: Here's a working example for you (notice the `dataType:'json'`): http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/bhXbh/59/

Comment: now it is giving me success if everything is right. but if i give wrong ip than it doesnot go in the complete. than how can i determine that something is wrong with the url or server is not running on the given port

Comment: Success doesn't mean that you get back what you want. Success means that the connection was successful. It's up to you to determine if the response is as expected.

Comment: If you want to handle an error response, use the `error()` function - works just like the success function but it has more valuable response data: `error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /* handle error */}`

Comment: now instead of complete() i used success and error function but it is going in success when connection established but not going in error when connection not proper

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the following (ref : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**xhrFields(added 1.5.1)Map**

A map of fieldName-fieldValue pairs to set on the native XHR object. For example, you can use it to set withCredentials to true for cross-domain requests if needed.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'a_cross_domain_url',
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

**crossDomain(added 1.5)**

Default: false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests

If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain